# Using INNER JOIN with HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

i´m triying to use an Inner join in a HQl Query but it does not work.

The query on SQL is:

```
SELECT A.first_name, F.title 
FROM film_actor X INNER JOIN actor A ON X.actor_id=A.actor_id
INNER JOIN film F ON F.film_id=X.film_id
```

It works perfectly, but when i use the same in HQL:

```
SELECT A.firstName, F.title 
FROM FilmActor X INNER JOIN Actor A ON X.actorId=A.actorId 
INNER JOIN Film F ON F.filmId=X.filmId
```

It shows this error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: outer or full join must be followed by path 
expression [SELECT A.firstName, F.title 
FROM sakila.entity.FilmActor X INNER JOIN Actor A ON X.actorId=A.actorId 
INNER JOIN Film F ON F.filmId=X.filmId]
```

Another HQL:

```
SELECT A.firstName, F.title 
FROM FilmActor as X INNER JOIN X.actorId as actor
INNER  JOIN X.filmId as film
```

Error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: actorId of: 
sakila.entity.FilmActor [SELECT A.firstName, F.title 
FROM sakila.entity.FilmActor as X INNER JOIN X.actorId as actor
INNER  JOIN X.filmId as film]
```

I tried a new one query

```
SELECT A.firstName, F.title 
FROM Actor A, Film F, FilmActor as X  INNER JOIN X.actor as actor 
INNER JOIN X.film as film
```

It is not exactly what i need but its a join query working so its something to start...

Actor mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD     3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 22-feb-2018 15:04:57 by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="sakila.entity.Actor" table="actor" catalog="sakila"     optimistic-lock="version">
    <id name="actorId" type="java.lang.Short">
        <column name="actor_id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="firstName" type="string">
        <column name="first_name" length="45" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="lastName" type="string">
        <column name="last_name" length="45" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="lastUpdate" type="timestamp">
        <column name="last_update" length="19" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <set name="filmActors" table="film_actor" inverse="true" lazy="true"         fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="actor_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="sakila.entity.FilmActor" />
    </set>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Film mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD     3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 22-feb-2018 15:04:57 by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="sakila.entity.Film" table="film" catalog="sakila"     optimistic-lock="version">
    <id name="filmId" type="java.lang.Short">
        <column name="film_id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="languageByLanguageId" class="sakila.entity.Language"         fetch="select">
        <column name="language_id" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="languageByOriginalLanguageId"     class="sakila.entity.Language" fetch="select">
        <column name="original_language_id" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="title" type="string">
        <column name="title" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="description" type="string">
        <column name="description" length="65535" />
    </property>
    <property name="releaseYear" type="date">
        <column name="release_year" length="0" />
    </property>
    <property name="rentalDuration" type="byte">
        <column name="rental_duration" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="rentalRate" type="big_decimal">
        <column name="rental_rate" precision="4" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="length" type="java.lang.Short">
        <column name="length" />
    </property>
    <property name="replacementCost" type="big_decimal">
        <column name="replacement_cost" precision="5" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="rating" type="string">
        <column name="rating" length="5" />
    </property>
    <property name="specialFeatures" type="string">
        <column name="special_features" length="54" />
    </property>
    <property name="lastUpdate" type="timestamp">
        <column name="last_update" length="19" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <set name="filmActors" table="film_actor" inverse="true" lazy="true"     fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="film_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="sakila.entity.FilmActor" />
    </set>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

FilmActor mapping:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
      <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
 <!-- Generated 22-feb-2018 15:04:57 by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
 <hibernate-mapping>
<class name="sakila.entity.FilmActor" table="film_actor" catalog="sakila" optimistic-lock="version">
    <composite-id name="id" class="sakila.entity.FilmActorId">
        <key-property name="actorId" type="short">
            <column name="actor_id" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="filmId" type="short">
            <column name="film_id" />
        </key-property>
    </composite-id>
    <many-to-one name="actor" class="sakila.entity.Actor" update="false"      insert="false" fetch="select">
        <column name="actor_id" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="film" class="sakila.entity.Film" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
        <column name="film_id" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="lastUpdate" type="timestamp">
        <column name="last_update" length="19" not-null="true" />
    </property>
</class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: HQL JOIN syntax is different. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-joins

Comment: I read it before but i couldn´t get any result, it showed a different error but didn´t work...

Comment: Then put that error along with the right HQL you used into the question. Maybe we can help.

Comment: I added the code. Thanks.

Comment: It would have been helpful to see `FilmActor` mapping and possibly also mapping for `Film` and `Actor` but I think HQL should be `SELECT A.firstName, F.title 
FROM FilmActor as X INNER JOIN X.actor as actor
INNER  JOIN X.film as film`.

Comment: I added all the mappings. Also i added a new join query that works, its not exactly what i need but its something to start... Thanks!

Comment: What part of new query is not exactly what you need?

Comment: I need a list of actors and the films where they appear.

Comment: Using this sentence : SELECT Distinct F.title FROM Film F, FilmActor X INNER join X.actor inner join X.film WHERE X.actor='1'   it shows a list of all films but no only the films from the actor with actorId=1 Whatis wrong?